# Задача как сделать проверку

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Хотел бы создать сайт на подобие турболикер, но не могу сделать проверку на like.getlist в php. Кто знает, как решить, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно выполнить HTTP запрос на [адрес API ВКонтакта](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests). Для метода [`likes.getlist()`](https://vk.com/dev/likes.getList) авторизация и access token не требуются.

Веб запрос в php я бы делал [с помощью CURL](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-exec.php):

```
<?php
$method = 'likes.getList';    
$params = array(
    'type' => 'post',
    'owner_id' => -29534144,
    'item_id' => 1373707,
);
$url = sprintf(
    'https://api.vk.com/method/%s?%s',
    $method,
    http_build_query( $params)
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_HEADER          => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 100,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => 'ddadw',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array('Accept-Language: ru,en-us'),
    CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => FALSE,
));

$vk = curl_exec( $curl);
$result = json_decode( $vk);
if( $result === NULL) exit('ошибка json decode');
if( isset( $result->error)) exit('Ошибка ВКонтакте');
if( isset( $result->response)  &&  isset( $result->response->users)  &&  is_array( $result->response->users)) {
    echo '<h4>Лайкнувшие</h4><ol>';
    foreach( $result->response->users AS $id) {
        printf( '<li><a href="http://vk.com/id%d" target="_blank">%d</a></li>', $id, $id); 
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}
```